# Redis SLOWLOG get output

Tags: redis

The `slowlog get` got the following result. The size of the `Hr:v1:Account` and `WorkflowService:v1:Summary:2022-05-25` are 64MB and 24MB respectively. Are the speeds too slow? What can be be checked?

```
> slowlog get
1) 1) "482470"
   2) "1659542506"
   3) "89761"
   4) 1) "HVALS"
      2) "Hr:v1:Account"
   5) "10.0.121.89:54200"
   6) "workflow-service-5cb4dd586f-lgk2t"
2) 1) "482469"
   2) "1659542040"
   3) "90711"
   4) 1) "HVALS"
      2) "Hr:v1:Account"
   5) "10.0.121.87:51498"
   6) "workflow-service-5cb4dd586f-b5hsv"
3) 1) "482468"
   2) "1659541603"
   3) "92399"
   4) 1) "HVALS"
      2) "Hr:v1:Account"
   5) "10.0.121.89:54200"
   6) "workflow-service-5cb4dd586f-lgk2t"
4) 1) "482467"
   2) "1659541138"
   3) "91147"
   4) 1) "HVALS"
      2) "Hr:v1:Account"
   5) "10.0.121.87:51498"
   6) "workflow-service-5cb4dd586f-b5hsv"
5) 1) "482466"
   2) "1659540701"
   3) "91263"
   4) 1) "HVALS"
      2) "Hr:v1:Account"
   5) "10.0.121.89:54176"
   6) "workflow-service-5cb4dd586f-lgk2t"
6) 1) "482465"
   2) "1659540235"
   3) "91721"
   4) 1) "HVALS"
      2) "Hr:v1:Account"
   5) "10.0.121.87:51490"
   6) "workflow-service-5cb4dd586f-b5hsv"
7) 1) "482464"
   2) "1659539799"
   3) "81112"
   4) 1) "HVALS"
      2) "Hr:v1:Account"
   5) "10.0.121.89:54166"
   6) "workflow-service-5cb4dd586f-lgk2t"
8) 1) "482463"
   2) "1659539790"
   3) "17437"
   4) 1) "HGETALL"
      2) "WorkflowService:v1:Summary:2022-05-25"
   5) "10.0.121.87:51462"
   6) "workflow-service-5cb4dd586f-b5hsv"
9) 1) "482462"
   2) "1659539721"
   3) "16732"
   4) 1) "HGETALL"
      2) "WorkflowService:v1:Summary:2022-05-25"
   5) "10.0.121.87:51462"
   6) "workflow-service-5cb4dd586f-b5hsv"
10) 1) "482461"
   2) "1659539332"
   3) "90810"
   4) 1) "HVALS"
      2) "Hr:v1:Account"
   5) "10.0.121.87:51462"
   6) "workflow-service-5cb4dd586f-b5hsv"
```

Answer (score 0):

`HGETALL` and `HVALS` are both O(N) where N is the size of the underlying hash, 90ms does not seem unreasonable given the rather large size of the hahses, particularly if those hashes many tiny fields rather than a few large fields that you are trying to pull back (that's just the time in redis, I imagine that there's a lot of time spent over the network pulling back that much data). If you need this to operate quicker, the main question to answer is "do I need all of the data I'm getting back from Redis?" If not, you can modify your access pattern to access via [`HMGET`](https://redis.io/commands/hmget/) so you can pull back a more surgical subset of the data that you actually need.